# Must bathroom linoleum be sealed and water tight?

Tags: bathroom, flooring

I got new linoleum fitted in a bathroom. After only 2 weeks black marks appeared on it. I contacted the fitters who had done the work. They came out and found nothing wrong *(in their eyes)*. I also had my Councillor & Housing Manager out to inspect it and they too said there was nothing wrong.

When I clean my floor the water is lying underneath as it was not sealed around the edges so the water is just seeping through. The company said they don't need to seal it .

My linoleum is completely ruined and when I lifted it up it came as one whole piece. Surly it should have been sealed to make it watertight?

Answer (score 1):

I would say that it absolutely should be sealed well all the way around the bathroom, and so that water cannot get underneath fixtures.

However, even on a floor that had no sealing at all I would not expect this kind of damage simply from mopping and minor spills. Do (did) you actually observe water being wicked out from the edge? Could it be that the toilet or another fixture was leaking and getting under the linoleum?